# Есть ли здесь приставка?

Tags: морфология, приставка, морфемный-разбор

Скажите, слово "недуг" делится на приставку и корень?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Нет, в современном языке в слове "недуг" выделяется лишь корень *недуг* и нулевое окончание.

Думаю, будет полезна историческая справка:

> «Не-» — отрицание; что же такое «-дуг»? Древнеславянское «дѫгъ» имело значение «здоровье», «сила»: примите в расчет наши «дужо́й», «дюжий» — они связаны с ним. Естественно, что значение слова «недуг» — «нездоровье», «болезнь».

Лев Успенский "Почему не иначе?"

Comment: Верно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Исторически делилось, сейчас не делится, это всё корень.

Comment: А почему же сейчас не делится на приставку и корень?

Comment: Потому что современный язык не знает, что такое "дуг".

Comment: Всё они знают. Дуг-Дюж - это коренное к понятию смочь, суметь, осилить.